# Opportunity to relocated HVAC system from attic to basement

Tags: hvac, basement, attic

Our >10-year old HVAC system (heat pump and 3-ton air handler) need to be replaced. The heat pump is need of new parts, but we were advised given the age of the entire system that it would be more sensible to replace rather than try to fix the heat pump (cost comparison we were quoted was $3500 for replacement parts and $8500 for system replacement). I'm cautiously looking at this as an opportunity to relocate the HVAC system into a roomier more conditioned part of the home.

Our current system is somewhat typical, we have an exterior heat pump located in front of the garage (which is connected to the unfinished basement), and the air handler located in the unvented attic which is under-insulated with about 4-inches of blown insulation on the floor. Ductwork is in good condition although will most likely need to be replaced in ~10 years. The attic has a low ceiling, I'm under 6'0" and have to bow 90-degrees to move at all, and I would prefer to use the attic for storage space (OR allow the opportunity to cathedral-ize the ceiling if we or another homeowner had an opportunity and want to do that), right now it is only useful as an incubator in the winter and oven in the summer.

The basement, although unfinished and not sealed on the exterior, is a larger space and kept at a reasonable temperature throughout most of the year. The only problem is that it requires a dehumidifier to keep it dry constantly because our home sits on a negative slope and the basement wasn't sealed on the exterior when it was built in 1962 (an interior perimeter drain and sump pump have been added on since construction).

I understand that relocating the HVAC system from the attic to the basement is an expensive project and will not likely be done for this current replacement project. I'm thinking it would be more feasible when the system is replaced again along with the ductwork but I want to know if this is one of those things I need to let go.

*EDIT: The house is a single-story in Zone 3 (just touching Zone 4). We plan on either moving the outlets from the ceiling to either the floor (horizontal) or vertically to lower side of the walls*

Comment: Is your house one story, two, something else (not including the basement)?

Comment: What are you planning on doing with your air registers (outlets)?  Are they currently in the ceiling?  If so, would you leave them there or move them to the floors?

Comment: How were you planning on cathedralizing the attic? Spray foam underneath, rigid insulation atop, or both?  Also, what climate zone are you in?

Comment: Are you asking if it is _possible_ to relocate the air handler? Are you asking if you _should_ do so? Are you asking if you should think about doing so at some point in the next 5-10 years so the next people can make a different modification to the house _if they wanted to_? I'm not really sure what's going on here...

Comment: I've addressed the above comments in above (italicized)